# Sqlalchemy remove from list - Flask current_user

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a weird behavior that I can't explain for now.

A user can be in many books, and a book can have many users.

Let's say we have a user table

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  books = db.relationship(
      'Book',
      secondary='user_book',
      backref='members',
      lazy='dynamic')
```

as well as a Book table:

```py
class Book(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

and the association table:

```py
class UserBook(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  user_id = db.Column(
      db.Integer(),
      db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
  book_id = db.Column(
      db.Integer(),
      db.ForeignKey('book.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

User has a method to leave a book:

```py
def leave_book(self, book):
  self.books.remove(book)
```

This method is unit tested and works correctly.

The problem is when making an API call and using current_user:

```py
@book_bp.route('/api/book/leave', methods=['DELETE'])
@login_required
def api_book_leave():
  book_id = request.json['book_id']
  book = Book.query.filter_by(id=book_id).first()
  # one of the following snippet is inserted here [1]
  try:
    db.session.commit()
  except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
    db.session.rollback()
    raise InternalServerError(
        description='An error occurred while leaving book.')
  return jsonify()
```

(keep in mind I stripped checks and validations from this snippet)

Here are different possibilities of what can replace [1]:

```py
current_user.leave_book(book)
# This doesn't remove the book from the user book list.
```

```py
book.members.remove(current_user)
# This removes the book from the user book list.
```

```py
user = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
user.leave_book(book)
# This removes the book from the user book list.
```

I'm confused as to why the query doesn't work if I use it on current_user, but works if I first query the user that has the id of current_user, and then remove the book.

Any hint is appreciated :)

edit: additional info regarding current_user, it's becoming weirder:

```py
user = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
print(current_user == user) # returns True
user.leave_book(book)
# This removes the book from the user book list.
```

Comment: Likely `current_user` is bound to a different session, but it's hard to say without a proper [mcve].

Comment: You might be correct, let me check. I added more info regarding current_user. Why do you think this is not a reproductible example? It has all the code needed IMO :)

Comment: So current_user in db.session returns False, but it also does the same for every other requests and they all go through. All other requests add stuff, for now this is the first one that deletes, I don't know if it's related.

Comment: As to the previous comment, I cannot take the code and use it to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can reproduce if your `@login_manager.user_loader` func doesn't query for the logged in user using the same db session as the requests threadlocal session, but that is just a guess.